# Intersection homology of orbifolds?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

It is well-known that the ordinary (singular) cohomology of orbifolds doesn't behave well for many purposes. Better approaches include the [Chen-Ruan cohomology](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2104605), which has an associative product structure closely tied with [orbifold Gromov-Witten theory](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1950941); another common approach is the Borel construction, replacing quotients by homotopy quotients.

Any orbifold has a natural stratification induced from the isomorphism type of the stabilizers. This stratification should allow one to talk about [intersection homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_homology) on orbifolds. It seems that this is an area that is not fully explored. Is there any study in this direction? What kind of expectations should one have? I'm happy to restrict to algebraic orbifolds.

Comment: Good question, I also thought about this when I first saw Chen-Ruan cohomology. When coefficients are characteristic 0, IH of orbifolds agrees with ordinary cohomology, so there is (sadly) nothing to see here.

Comment: Consider a chart for an orbifold, of the form $V/G$ for some finite group $G$. The applying the Decomposition Theorem (achtung overkill!) for $V \to V/G$ we conclude that the constant sheaf appears as a direct summand, and hence must be the IC sheaf.

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson I do not see why this is an obstruction: Chen-Ruan cohomology is ordinary cohomology of the inertia stack (see Emily Clader's notes here http://www-personal.umich.edu/~eclader/OctLect1.pdf). Therefore, why not trying to consider ordinary intersection homology of the inertia stack?

Comment: @Cisinski: Ahh, I had never thought of this! It is very possible that this works.

Comment: @D.-C. Cisinski: The inertia stack of an orbifold is another orbifold, so if intersection cohomology is ordinary cohomology for orbifolds, the same holds for inertia stacks of orbifolds.

Comment: @JohnPardon Well, the principle still holds. We can still work with a possibly singular version of orbifolds (objects which are locally quotients by the action of a finite group of stratified spaces of some sort, whether it would be pseudo-manifolds à la Banagl or conically stratified spaces or what not) and we will still get a Chen-Ruan version of intersection homology.

Comment: @JohnPardon Moreover, even in the smooth case, intersection homology of the naive quotient $V/G$ will be interesting a priori, since this quotient is possibly singular. Even with coefficient in a field of characteristic zero, that gives a cute perspective on the cohomology of orbifolds vs intersection homology of their coarse moduli space.